# jquery resizable not working in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I just can't figure out why this is not working. Been stuck on this for a while now. All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Here is my aspx page:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.5.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ng-ckeditor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Summaries.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/ng-ckeditor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Summaries.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

            <div class="ui-widget-content" id="try" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #f00;"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#try").resizable({
            maxHeight: 1200
        });
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI depends on jQuery. Judging off your code, you're only including jQuery UI.

Add

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

to your scripts.

Check your console as it stands, you should see `jQuery is not defined`.

Comment: no, Im sorry, my mistake. jquery core is in my master page. No such error in the console.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? Here's a [JSBin of an HTML equiv](http://jsbin.com/pucece/1/edit?html,js,output) that works fine. Sorry, I'm not well versed enough in ASP.NET to debug that side of things.

Comment: no errors. Could it be angular interfering. I have my angular and jquery in the same javascript file.

Comment: Well nothing is wrong with your javascript. I'd focus on importing the scripts correctly.